# How to call jQuery Lightbox with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox2

How can I call jQuery Lightbox2 with AJAX.

I am using this function for my project.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".paylasimi-goster").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "gonderiyi_goster.php?msg_id=" + id,
            type: 'get',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loader").fadeIn(100);
            },
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#loader").fadeOut(100);
            $(".sidebar").fadeIn().find(".sidebar-content").animate({
                "right": 0
            }, 200).html(data);
            imgResize(jQuery, 'smartresize');
        });
    });

    $(".sidebar").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar-content").animate({
            "right": "-565px"
        }, 200, function() {
            $(".sidebar").fadeOut();
        })

    });
    $(".sidebar-content").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Also I have created this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8bwms9mu/6/)** from jsfiddle. In this jsfiddle you can see there white div. Click any white div then see the right sidebar. So in the sidebar have one image. The problem is here : `Lightbox2` does not work when you click on the image.

How can I call Lightbox2 with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the `e. stopPropagation()` on the `.sidebar-content` click event which is preventing the lightbox from triggering. You can remove that altogether and inside the `.sidebar` click event instead call:

```
$(".sidebar").click(function(e){
     var preventClick = $(".sidebar-content");

     if (!preventClick.is(e.target) && preventClick.has(e.target).length === 0){
       //run the hide animate function + callback 
       $(".sidebar-content").animate({"right":"-200px"},200,function(){
           $(".sidebar").fadeOut();   
       });
     };     
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bwms9mu/8/)